# How to truncate a file using javascript (no jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, file, blob

I need to truncate a video file into a certain section(not-yet-uploaded-section), before uploading it to a server.  The file is selected using the html input element.

I am unsure how to use blob.slice().
This is my attempt but it does not appear to work.

```
var startByte = x;
var endByte = y;

var inputFile = document.getElementById('inPutId');
var vidFile = inputFile.files[0];
var slicedFile = vidFile.slice(x, y);
```

Comment: A video file is not just a bunch of data, it has a specific data format depending on the video type (.avi, .mpeg, .mp4, etc). You cannot just trim its data stream and hope it's still valid. You need to deal with its frames and metadata properly. I'd advise you to just mark the starting and ending points (maybe with HTML5 `<video>` tag) and submit it along with the full video to the server, where you would cut it properly. I don't know what backend technology you are using, but there is a plenity of libraries for video editing on the server side.

Comment: What you have seems to work just fine, it slices the file, but as noted above slicing off parts of a video file could make it not play at all, it's not as easy as just cutting of pieces of binary data.

Comment: I'm using third  party API and sending the file with appropriate headers so their backend deals with the rest of the voodoo.  I am trying to handle connectivity issues and upload the file where I last left off. I hope that clears things up a little.

Comment: There's no way for the API to recreate bytes that are lost by your truncation.

Comment: Is your plan that you'll run this code multiple times, so that it should eventually send the whole file, and the back end puts it back together?

Comment: i send the file, and if I get reconnected, I request the server to determine how much of my file made it safely.  I then re-send the parts of the file that has yet to be received by the server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if you could recursively loop through

```
var z=size_of_slice; 
var slicedFile = vidFile.substr(0, y);
check_if_slice_is_valid(slicedFile) ? upload(slicedFile) : y=y+z;
```